# Adding context menu to tree view by XAML only

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contextmenu

Trying to add a context menu to a `TreeView` with just xaml code.

- Tv Show

  - Season 1
  - Season n

The context menu should only show when I right click a Season node.

Is that possible? I know how to solve it with code behind, but I'd like to learn to use WPF as it is intended. I have trouble finding out if I should be able to solve this with using only xaml.

Current xaml:

```
    <TreeView 
        Grid.Row="1" 
        Grid.Column="0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding TvShows}" x:Name="TvShowsTreeView"
        SelectedItemChanged="TvShowsTreeViewOnSelectedItemChanged">

        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="tvShows:TvShow" ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: How are you constructing the tree? by using `HierarchicalDataTemplate`? post your current XAML.

Comment: @HighCore, added xaml. Also have some "try" with the context menu, but it didn't lead to much yet, so I left it out for now, hoping on something that does make sense from SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `ItemTemplate` property of `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. It should look like this:

```
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="tvShows:TvShow" ItemsSource="{Binding Seasons}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="TypeOfSeasonInYourApplication">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <!-- Place MenuItems here -->
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

I actually didn't test that myself so please let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Nope, not quite: Property 'VisualTree' does not support values of type 'DataTemplate'.

Comment: Hmm, strange, that used to work in my case.
By the error message you wrote I can only advice you to doublecheck if you placed `DataTemplate` inside of `ItemTemplate` property and not in `HierarchicalDataTemplate` itself (that wouldn't work for sure).